# "bash: fork: retry: No child processes " when running docker quick start terminal or in /git bash shell

Tags: git, bash, docker

when I am using Docker quick start terminal following error appears "bash: fork: retry: No child processes " even its same when I am using git bash shell. I think my system is unable to load bash shell properly. could someone please help in resolving this issue.

System: Windows 7
Memory: 8gb
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjZM5.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try not to use quicktart or any bash.

From a regular CMD, check where docker-machine.exe is installed (or copy it directly from https://github.com/docker/machine/releases)

Then type:

```
docker-machine ls
# if you see one machine "default"
docker machine start
docker-machine ssh
```

If there is no machine:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

Again, no bash required at any point.

Comment: It's working Thanks! but, you might have seen my error screenshot. do you know what does it mean? any inputs are really appreciated.

Comment: It might be related to the version of git (if it an old version, it would be an old bash)

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to some resource limit, either on the server itself (or) specific to your user account. Limits in your shell could be checked via `ulimit -a`. Esp check for `ulimit -u` max user processes, if you have reached max processes, fork is unable to create any new and failing with that error. This could also be due to `swap/memory` resource issue